# Show/Hide Div in a PHP While Loop

Tags: php, jquery

I have file where I'm looping through all events I have in a database and then putting them on the page. I have a button a div at the end of each event div when clicked I would like for that specific div to open. Nothing I've tired works it either opens every div or none at all.

Here's my for the icon to click and expand.

```
echo "<div id='" . $row['Event ID'] . "' class=\"schedcol schedspan_1_of_12 cellalign expand\"><i class=\"fa fa-arrow-down\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i><br><span>EXPAND<span></div>";
```

Here's my code for what I want to expand

```
echo "<div class=\"list\" style=\"display: none;\">";
    echo "<p> " . $row['First Place'] . ", " . $row['Second Place'] . ", ". $row['Third Place'] . "</p>";
echo "</div>";
```

Here's my javascript

```
    echo "<script>";
        echo "jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#$eventid').on('click', function(event) {        
                jQuery('.list').toggle('show');
            });
        });";
    echo "</script>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `event-row` class and put the id in a `data-id=""` attribute

```
echo "<div data-id='" . $row['Event ID'] . "' class=\"event-row schedcol schedspan_1_of_12 cellalign expand\"><i class=\"fa fa-arrow-down\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i><br><span>EXPAND<span></div>";
```

Then at the html you want to expand you also add a `data-id=""` attribute

```
echo "<div data-id='" . $row['Event ID'] . "' class=\"list\" style=\"display: none;\">";
    echo "<p> " . $row['First Place'] . ", " . $row['Second Place'] . ", ". $row['Third Place'] . "</p>";
echo "</div>";
```

Then outside the loop you put your script

```
echo '<script>
    jQuery(".event-row").each(function(){
        const $this = jQuery(this);
        const id = $this.attr("data-id");
        $this.find("span:contains(EXPAND)").click(function() {
            jQuery(".list[data-id="+id+"]").toggle("show");
        });
    });
</script>';
```